# How do you convert double quoted integer to integer?

Tags: javascript, parseint

How do I parse this to int?

`"'10'"`

Thanks.

Comment: I don't care for String.replace solutions.

Comment: you mean... var a = "'10'" ?

Comment: No, that's not an integer. I mean `var a=10;`.

Comment: Ok... let me rephrase... you want to start with a = "'10'" and parse it into a = 10?  Well.. once the author of the answer below finishes testing the regular expression.. I'd think it's the simplest solution to use.... maybe with parseInt to it

Comment: `"'10'"` is just a string. You can assign it to a variable called `a` if you like I guess.

Comment: What exactly is your need other than having the int parsed out? Performance? or just collecting fancy ways to do it?

Comment: Yet another way (but not really elegant): `parseInt(str.replace("'", ''), 10)`. Or with regex: `+str.replace(/'/g, '')`. If you had double quotes in the string, i.e. `'"10"'`, you could use `+JSON.parse(str)`. There are so many ways to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really don't want to use `replace`, you can do

```
 var num = +str.match(/\d+/)
```

or

```
 var num = +str.slice(1,-1)
```

Comment: I don't want to use replace to not start-up the RegEx engine. Nice solution though.

Comment: The slice solution is pretty cute. Thanks. I'll give it a bit more time to see other suggestions.

Comment: There are also eval solutions or disguised eval ones like `var num = new Function("return +"+str)();`. But that would be so slow I won't write them in my answer.

Comment: Yes, slice is what I would have recommended, too. As you already know you want that string execpt the first and last character, this is the straight forward solution.

Comment: @Francisc: Use the solution that is most understandable. The regex solution is easy to understand because it's clear that you are trying to extract digits. The slice solution is elegant, but it's not obvious why the first and last characters have to be removed (without knowing the value).

Comment: I agree Felix, but adding a quick comment saying what I'm doing makes it elegant AND understandable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
var num = +str.split("'")[1]
```